# CMSIS-RTOS2 message consumption from queue

Tags: stm32, rtos, cmsis

The [docs](https://arm-software.github.io/CMSIS_5/RTOS2/html/group__CMSIS__RTOS__Message.html#gad90d4959466a7a65105061da8256ab9e) do not explicitly mention if a successfully received (`get()`) message is then wiped from the queue, aka "consumed". Is this unclear in the docs or do i have to delete the message manually? If so, how can i achieve that?

Comment: The semantics of the queue would suggest the former is true, and it is not a "hole", it is implied.

Comment: It seems like it would be a strange queue if the message is not consumed and has to be deleted manually by a process which is not mentioned in the documentation. Also, is the source not available? Can you not check the source?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, receiving or getting an item from the queue implies that the item is removed from the queue. The usage example is provided in the documentation of [`osMessageQueuePut`](https://arm-software.github.io/CMSIS_5/RTOS2/html/group__CMSIS__RTOS__Message.html#gaa515fc8b956f721a8f72b2c505813bfc).

Typically, there is not a separate API to remove a single item from a queue, if you want to do that, just receive the item and do nothing with it.

`osMessageQueueReset` would clear all items, while `osMessageQueueDelete` deletes the queue itself.

Some APIs do have ability to get an item from the queue without removing it. Typically, such API would use a term "**peek**". CMSIS-RTOS2 API does not seem to have such a function, but you can see FreeRTOS [`xQueuePeek`](https://www.freertos.org/xQueuePeek.html) for an example.

Comment: Using `osMessageQueueGetCount()` reveals that the queue indeed decrements the number of its messages after a successful `get()`. I had overlooked this function, my bad. Thanks for your response.